# How can I reduce the following code in single line 'for' loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have following code.

```
for i in range(1,number):
    if (number%i) == 0:
        divisorSum += i
```

How can I reduce this code in just one line in python

Comment: Don't reduce everything to one line in Python, it's well written and clear.

Comment: I was just trying to learn how to do that. Does it affect computation time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
divisorSum += sum(i for i in range(1, number) if number % i == 0)
```

Whether this is more, or less, readable than the original is in the eye of the beholder.

I've used `+=` to keep the code exactly equivalent to yours. If you initialize `divisorSum` to zero before the loop, you can replace `+=` with `=` and get rid of the initialization.

Finally, it's worth noting that your code only computes [proper divisors](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperDivisor.html). If you do need to include the number itself, use `range(1, number + 1)`.

Comment: +1 for *Whether this is more, or less, clear than the original is in the eye of the beholder.*

Answer (score 1):

You can try using filter:

```
sum( filter(lambda i: not number % i, range(1,7)) )
```

Note that in Python, `0` is `False`. So `not 0` is `True`. `not number % i` Checks for your stipulated condition. `sum` does the addition that you do iteratively.

Comment: But you know what Guido thinks about `lambda`... :)

Comment: I think he said something about admitting defeat :). https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-February/060415.html. Unfortunately `reduce` in gone in 3.0. All hail the `lambda`